# Is there any way to find who recorded conference in skype for business

Tags: lync, skype, skype-for-business-2016

We have to find out who has recorded a conference (I mean who pressed a record button during conference) in our s4b 2016 onprem. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: AFAIK When recording was allowed at all then only the organiser / presenter could record a conference in Skype for business,  is there actually anything to investigate?  - Did you check your logs already?  Because often the information you need will only be in your logs when you had configured the correct level of logging beforehand.

Comment: Yes, I think if we check client logs, there are some usefull information (correct me if I wrong) - as far as I can see, strings "<msci:client-recording/>" indicate that recording is in place.
But is there any way to get that information on server side, cause logs can be overriten or something like that.

Comment: I would enable the auditing feature as a gpo, if the user tries to access the file it will be logged. but remember that it could be against the law.  but this kind will only work in the future.  But remember that it might be a workaround to use a other software to record video and audio